# git push failing suddenly (git-remote-https: relocation error)

Tags: linux, git, debian

I've pushed to my repo less than an hour before. Now I get this error:

```
$ git push origin master
git-remote-https: relocation error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: symbol pt(read_mutex_destroy, version GLIBC_2.0 not defined in file libpthread.so.0 with link time reference
```

I'm running Debian Wheezy, and didn't install anything or run any upgrade.

Comment: Set up your remote again and then try

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up your remote head again. The pointer might have got corrupted.

```
git remote set-head <name>
```

Answer (score -1):

This work for me :

```
$ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn2/libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libidn2-0_2.0.4-1.1build2_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-mark hold libidn2-0
```